# There is no photo library but pictures are still visible in Photos app

Tags: photos.app

I learnt that by default the Photos app maintains a photo library within the pictures folder of my user account on my MacBook Pro. However, there is no such library in the pictures folder. I have searched thoroughly, but cannot find it in any other location either! Even so, my Photos app still displays my photos.

What could be the reason for this? Where's my Photos Library?

Answer (score 1):

The default location for the photo library is `~/Pictures/`, but it's possible that it's different for you. Open the Photos app, open the Preferences pane and the General tab will show you the location of your photo library.

[image]

Comment: it is showing Pictures only, but when I go to Pictures folder, I do not find any library

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try either of the following...

**Method 1**

This basically adds on the answer by Glorfindel:

- Launch the Photos App
- Go to Photos > Preferences
- Select the General tab
- Click on the <kbd>Show in Finder</kbd> button that appears below the Library Location path

Does that open the folder in the Finder, thereby revealing it to you?

**Method 2**

If the first method doesn't work, try this instead:

- Ensure Photos is **not** already running
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Launch the Photos app, still keeping the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you see the Choose Library window
- This window gives you a number of options, however the last opened Photos Library should be highlighted on the list. If not, select it.
- Now look below the list but above the buttons. You should see a file path listed for where the library is located

Does that file path reveal where your library is located?